# Chef: Count the number of files in a folder

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to get the count of files in a folder and skip or execute the further resources based on the count.

```
file 'C:\Users\Desktop\Chef-file\count.txt' do
            dir = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Chef-Commands'
                count = Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count { |file| File.file?(file)}
              content count
            end
```

But getting the following error

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Property content must be one of: String, nil!  You passed 0.
```

I am pretty new to chef and ruby so was wondering how to fix/solve this problem.

Once the count is obtained, how to check its value in other resources?

Also would like to know if  this is the right approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` seems to be `0` (Fixnum).

You may wanna try:

```
file 'C:\Users\Desktop\Chef-file\count.txt' do
  dir = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Chef-Commands'
  count = Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count { |file| File.file?(file)}
  content count.to_s
end
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will check at compile time, nor converge time.

Comment: This worked but always gives 0 as the the number of files...need to figure that out..